# Can't uninstall a driver program

Tags: windows-vista, drivers

I downloaded a driver for a camcorder (Sony USB Driver) so that it could connect to my computer (Windows Vista - 32 bit). The driver was incompatible with Vista, so to install it I used the process decribed [here](http://support.sony-europe.com/dime/downloads/downloads.aspx?&f=usbdrven_vista&site=odw_en_GB)

(ran it in compatibility mode for XP).

I now suspect that this driver is causing issues in my PC. However, when I go to the "Uninstall or Change a Program" screen and try to select and uninstall it, I get the error message that "USB driver cannot be installed in the current version of Windows"

I tried using device manager to uninstall it too, but I couldn't find the driver there.
I also tried to run the setup file again so that it would give me the option to uninstall it, but that just prompted me to install it again.

Is there any other way for me to uninstall this driver, or to run the uninstaller in compatibility mode for XP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I installed that on a test VM, and had all the same errors you did when trying to ininstall it. I did a little search of the registry for Sony here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

The search for "Sony" returned this key, and I looked at the uninstall routine:

```
{5C29CB8B-AC1E-4114-8D68-9CD080140D4A}
```

So I went back to my setup.exe program (the one that you already set to run in XP SP3 compatibility mode), and ran this command in the run box:

```
c:\filelocation\setup.exe /uninstall
```

It uninstalled perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Run [RevoUninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/start_freeware_download.html) and ignore the warnings. Even if the uninstaller fails, Revo will still search your system for traces (in files and registry) of the driver and remove them manually.

Then use [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) to search for any final traces by looking for drivers and applications published by Sony.